# Assign script to run if cell data validation is "true"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

What I'm trying to do is create an if statement for my code to run automatically as soon as a certain cell in the sheet has a data validation of "true" and not be assigned to a button because when I share the google sheet my users don't have access to click on the button. Unless I'm doing something wrong?

```
function ds631321() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('HUSSAR');
  var val = templateSheet.getRange('A$1').getValue();
  let result; 
    if (val = true) {
      function so5691088602() {
        const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        const templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('HUSSAR');
        const dateStart = templateSheet.getRange('C$2').getValue();
        const numDups = 1;
        const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
          for (let i = 1; i <= numDups; i++) {
            const sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(dateStart, timezone, 'MMMM yyyy');
            const newSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, { template: templateSheet });
            const dataRange = newSheet.getDataRange();
            dataRange.setValues(dataRange.getValues());
  }
    }
    }}
```

Kind Regards,
Richard

Comment: 1. `if (val = true)` it should be `if (val == true)`; 2. How exactly this cell is supposed to change? With a formula? Scripts can't run by a formula.

Comment: 3. And you define the `function so5691088602()` but you never call it. There should be a line like: `so5691088602();` somewhere to run this function.

Comment: Oh so scripts cant be triggered by a formula? So if the cell A1 changes to TRUE for the script to pickup there has been a edit to that specific cell and then runs the script?

Comment: Yes. You can run the script manually. Or you can run this script by a trigger. There are different triggers: `onEdit()` (when you manually edit the sheet), `onOpen()` (when you open the sheet), time driven trigger. Etc

Comment: The function will be run when there is an edit on the specific cell? Oky im clearly misunderstanding javascript then here

Comment: I understand, but there should be a way to trigger it onEdit() but only if that specific cell gets edited?

Comment: Yes. You can use `onEdit()`. But it should be manual typing inside a sheet (or select from dropdown list, etc). Not by formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createTimeBasedTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction("ds631321")).length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("ds631321").timeBased().everyMinutes(15).create();
  }
}

function ds631321() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('HUSSAR');
  var val = templateSheet.getRange('A$1').getValue();
  let result;
  if (val = true) {
    function so5691088602() 
  }
}
```